# Simple Dynamic Variable Name EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i need to set a variable name that changes within a loop. Please look below:

The result i need is:

```
Vari1 = 1
Vari2 = 2
Vari3 = 3
```

What i tried:

```
for i = 1 to 3

Vari(i) = i      ' (Vari & i) also doesnt work

next i
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Don't create variables dynamically, use array instead

Comment: ^ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays

Answer (score 0):

First return the dynamic `i` from your code somehow (simplified below) then resize your array:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Vari() As Long
Dim i As Long, x As Long

'Get value of i somehow
i = 3

ReDim Vari(1 To i)
For x = 1 To i
    Vari(x) = x
Next x

End Sub
```

Or populate a `Variant` data type array directly through `Evaluate`:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Vari() As Variant
Dim i As Long

'Get value of i somehow
i = 3

Vari = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & i & "))")

End Sub
```